# monitor printing in wpf .net c# program windows printer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i have a problem with the last print job here the code run in a loop every 1 second to monitor
print jobs and when the last one come its printing it but going into the if(intprint=0 && jobprint>0)
even when not actually printing something because the printer not yet clear the queue how can i make this right and make sure that its trigger the error meesage only when trying to print over the print limit(0)

```
   private void StartTimer()
        {
            allowErorsNum = 1;
            timer1 = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer1.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000); // Check every 1 seconds
            timer1.Tick += Timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Start();
        }


        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\cimv2");
                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PrintJob");

                using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
                {
                    ManagementObjectCollection printJobs = searcher.Get();
                    int jobCount = printJobs.Count;

                    if (jobCount > 0 && intPrints != 0)
                    {
                        if (jobCount <= intPrints && intPrints != 1)
                        {
                            // Update DB (if applicable)
                            updateDownPrint(intPrints, phone1, jobCount, newCon1);
                        }

                        else if (intPrints == 1)
                        {

                            MessageBox.Show(intPrints.ToString());

                            // Update DB (if applicable)
                            updateDownPrint(intPrints, phone1, jobCount, newCon1);
                        }
                 }
                    else if (intPrints == 0 && jobCount > 0)
                    {
                        int jobId = 0;

                        //MessageBox.Show(intPrints.ToString());
                        if (allowErorsNum >= 1)
                        {
                            allowErorsNum--;
                            MessageBox.Show("you dont have any prints left error!!!", "error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                        }
                        // Stop the print jobs
                        foreach (ManagementObject job in printJobs)
                        {
                            jobId = Convert.ToInt32(job.Properties["JobId"].Value);
                            // Now you can use the jobId as needed.
                            Console.WriteLine($"Print Job ID: {jobId}");
                        }

                        CancelPrintJob("Microsoft PCL6 Class Driver", jobId);
                    }
                
            }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
            }

        }
```

im trying it on virtual printer so i dont know how much time its going to take to clear the print queue
maybe thats the problem but i cant find virtual printer which accually "printing"